# Pass a variable between functions

Tags: php

I need to pass $a['msg'] to the second function (in php). I've tried global variables and evidently, I'm doing it wrong. Can someone please help.

```
function shreinlink_func( $atts ) 
{

    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' => 'something',
        'msg' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    return "<a onclick=\"shreinpop()\" data-emailID=\"shreinpop\" href=\"{$a['url']}\">Email</a>";

} 

add_shortcode( 'shreinlink', 'shreinlink_func' );

function shreinlink_head() 
{

    echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            function shreinpop() {
            alert($a['msg']);
        }
        </script>
    "; 

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'shreinlink_head' );
```

Comment: Read about [PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).

Comment: You need to cover the basics @chuckscoggins

Comment: @Arslan.H I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @chuckscoggins i mean that you should cover some basic things.You need to understand classes and functions, there is no point of doing it the way 'make it work' you won't improve your self, and you wont learn anything new.My strong advice is to check the PHP documentation page....

Comment: @Arslan.H I only turned to SO after reading about functions, scope, global variables, etc. all day long. I came here because I was trying to learn what I was doing wrong.

It turns out, the second function was being called in the header and the first function was being called in the body, so the variable was never getting into the second function.

It would've been great if you'd helped me figure that out instead of lecturing me about how I needed to "understand." I don't understand the purpose of commenting on people's posts if you're only going to fuss at their question.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider function scope and function variables. They are valid within the function and only there, then garbage collection takes place.

An option for you is to set the variable $a outside the function and change the value of it inside the function, then access it again inside your other function. You would have to use

```
$this->a['msg']
```

You could also pass $a as a reference and manipulate it within your function, [Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), and then use that array in your other function.